# Probability computation $P(X_n/\log(n))$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ denotes a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $X_1$ ~ $exp(1)$ and c>0.
What is $P( X_n/\log(n) > c$ for infinitely many $n$'s) ?

Can I simply say that $P(X_n > c \cdot \log(n)) = 1/(n^c)$, where $c > 0$; and with the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, the probability is $1$ if $c \le 1$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: "Can I simply say...": Only if you can prove it.  Can you?  Without knowing more about the distribution of the $X_n$, I don't think you can.

Comment: added some Infos - sorry :)

Comment: Now you can indeed "simply say that..." what you suggest.